# Prosemirror Editor DOMParser Issue

Tags: javascript, editor, tiptap, prose-mirror, remirror

I have tried to parse the below HTML string using prosemirror Editor DOMParser

```
const initialValue = '<p><span style="font-size:36px;"><span style="color:#00ff22;"><span style="background-color:#77b9c9;">hhkjhk hkjhkjh hjkhkj</span></span></span></p>'
DOMParser.fromSchema(schema).parse(document.createRange().createContextualFragment(initialValue))
```

This is the actual initial HTML

```
<p>
     <span style="font-size:36px;">
         <span style="background-color:#77b9c9;">
            <span style="color:#00ff22;">world !!!</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</p>
```

but I got

```
<p>
   <span style="color:#00ff22;">world !!!</span>
</p>
```

The issue is some of the span tags were removed even if it has style tag in it

how do achieve the exact HTML without losing some span tags? please help me with the necessary schema